# Data mining or machine learning

Tags: discussion, support, bug

As part of comment In one of my posts or flaggings, I mentioned machine learning instead of data mining. There is no excuse for my wrong posting or flagging. Is this the reason that my posts are no longer accepted or the reason for my timed suspension in many sites including the AI site?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the reason. The reason is that you create posts whose content is off-topic. Please, see [our on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please, read it very carefully (especially, the notes)! If something is unclear there, please, let me know or ask another meta-question.